# Where is the preference list for "open with" applications?

Tags: preferences, plist

I'm getting an (error code -10813) when trying to set file extensions to open with a certain app in Mountain Lion 10.8.5. Where is the plist file that has those preferences so that I can delete it and hopefully end this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is not a duplicate. Only the answer (which did not seem to help here) is a duplicate. The question should be rephrased though to address the real issue here (the -10813 error), not the search for a list which probably does not exist (in a humanly readable form).

Answer (score 1):

See the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68600/903) for [Why does my Mac's list of “Open with” applications start listing the apps twice and sometimes three times?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68596/why-does-my-macs-list-of-open-with-applications-start-listing-the-apps-twice):

> This happens because the LaunchServices database gets corrupted.
>
> To fix on Mountain Lion:
>
> 1. Open Terminal.app in the /Applications/Utilities/ folder.
> 2. run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`
> 3. Restart
>
> This [hint on Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031215144430486) covers the command for other Mac OS versions over the years.

Comment: This just messed everything up on El Capitan and **didn't** fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this problem you need to rebuild your launch services.

You can go through the steps as mentioned by David. But you can easily do the same work of rebuilding the Launch Services database using the free [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) tool by going to the **Maintenance > Rebuild > Launch Services** menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Error -10813 appears to mean

> Data of the desired type is not available (for example, there is no
>   kind string)

i.e., some entry in the app's plist file is missing as far as I understand. I do not know which fields are required, but I had the same error in the same situation. In my case, it could be resolved by adding a value to the field "CFBundleIdentifier".

This is best done using XCode as it displays the XML structure of the file nicely (and somehow changes the keyword names along the way, so the entry to change was "Bundle identifier" here). But any other text editor can be used as well if XCode is not available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! And thank you for providing your answer. :) Can I suggest you provide more detail or context so your answer can help as many users as possible? For example, it'd be good if you could add some info on *how* you actually added a value to the *Bundle Identifier* field? I suspect most users will have no idea where to begin. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.