# Monterey "You are opening the application LibreOffice for the first time" every time I launch the program

Tags: monterey, libreoffice, macos

I have restarted the computer.

I have tried the accepted solution to [this similar question from over a decade ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30177).

But macOS keeps behaving poorly.

How to I get macOS to stop asking this every time I lauch the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to launch LibreOffice by clicking its icon (which I rarely do), rather than launching it by opening a document such as an .odt, .docx, .ods, or .xlsx file (which I do all the time).

Once I launched it (from the Dock icon) macOS was able to register my permission for the app permanently.